# Proving the Riemann integrability of a function

Tags: riemann-integration

Let $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Riemann integrable function. If $g : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is another function and $S = \lbrace x : f(x) \neq g(x)\rbrace$ contains exactly $n$ points, show that $g$ is also Riemann integrable from any of the equivalent definitions of Riemann integrability. Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: One of the equivalent definitions is that a bounded function is Riemann integrable iff it is continuous almost everywhere, i.e., everywhere except on a set of measure zero.

Comment: The laziest could be [Lebesgue's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability). You only need to realize that $S$, being finite, is of measure zero. Therefore, the points of discontinuity of $g$ are those of $f$ changed by possibly a subset of $S$, which results in a set of measure zero.

Comment: These n points have to be discontinuous, and also then each function can be thought of as covering same area except since point discontinuities don't affect area over x-axis...hope this helps.

Comment: One of my concerns is that what dose the set S imply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S:=\{x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n}\}$.
I will suppose below that $a<x_{1}$ and $x_{n}<b$.
Clearly, $S$ is isolated.
Thus, we can find $\delta>0$ such that $x_{k+1}-x_{k}>2\delta$.
We may also suppose that $x_{1}-a>\delta$ and $b-x_{n}>\delta$.
Now, consider the following.
\begin{align}
\int_{a}^{b}f(u)\mathrm{d}u
={}&\int_{a}^{x_{1}-\delta}f(u)\mathrm{d}u+\int_{x_{1}+\delta}^{x_{2}-\delta}f(u)\mathrm{d}u+\cdots+\int_{x_{n-1}+\delta}^{x_{n}-\delta}f(u)\mathrm{d}u+\int_{x_{n}+\delta}^{b}f(u)\mathrm{d}u\\
{}&+\int_{x_{1}-\delta}^{x_{1}+\delta}f(u)\mathrm{d}u+\cdots+\int_{x_{n}-\delta}^{x_{n}+\delta}f(u)\mathrm{d}u\\
={}&\int_{a}^{x_{1}-\delta}g(u)\mathrm{d}u+\int_{x_{1}+\delta}^{x_{2}-\delta}g(u)\mathrm{d}u+\cdots+\int_{x_{n-1}+\delta}^{x_{n}-\delta}g(u)\mathrm{d}u+\int_{x_{n}+\delta}^{b}g(u)\mathrm{d}u\tag{1}\label{eq1}\\
{}&+\int_{x_{1}-\delta}^{x_{1}+\delta}f(u)\mathrm{d}u+\cdots+\int_{x_{n}-\delta}^{x_{n}+\delta}f(u)\mathrm{d}u.\tag{2}\label{eq2}
\end{align}
Note that as $\delta\to0$, each term in \eqref{eq2} tends to $0$,
and \eqref{eq1} becomes $\int_{a}^{b}g(u)\mathrm{d}u$.

Comment: Minor typo: I think the integrals in the last line of your equation should have $g(u)$ as the integrand.

Comment: @hryghr Nope, $f$ and $g$ are different on those intervals (but sure the integrals are the same), so keep it as is.

Comment: My bad, misread the integration limits.

Comment: Actually, a proof by using partitions would be much better. I can say that this is some kind of cheating...